# PHP replace a character in string fetched from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to replace a string which contains value with operator : like "2456:72" to "2456.72" where data is fetched from mysql, I tried using `str_replace` which sucks. `$row_loop3["Tot_minutes"]` is the row which I should replace the character, please find my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("172.16.10.102", "******", "RND@ISO-3306", "eTrans");
if (!$mysqli->multi_query("call sp_get_Android_Online_minutes_Chart ('2015-01-01','2016-01-30')")) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
}
do {
    if ($res_loop3 = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        $response_loop3["minutes"] = array();
        $find                      = ":";
        $re                        = ".";

        while ($row_loop3 = $res_loop3->fetch_assoc()) {
            $j                            = 5;
            $value_loop3                  = array();
            $value_loop3["File_Day"]      = $row_loop3["edit_date"];
            $value_loop3["File_Minutes"]  = $row_loop3["FileDay"];
            $val["Tot1_Minutes"]          = $row_loop3["Tot_minutes"];
            $value_loop3["Total_Minutes"] = str_replace($val, $find, $re); //value which I should replace : with .
            array_push($response_loop3["minutes"], $value_loop3);
            $response_loop3["success"] = 1;
        }

        echo $merger = json_encode(array_merge($response, $response_loop2, $response_loop3));

        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
```

please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any errors?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer No, am getting result as {"File_Day":"2015-01-02","File_Minutes":"2","Total_Minutes":"."}, where entire string is replaced by "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making variable instead you are making associative array.
change this

```
 $val["Tot1_Minutes"] = $row_loop3["Tot_minutes"];
```

to

```
 $val= $row_loop3["Tot_minutes"];
```

and also order in str function to

```
$val = $row_loop3["Tot_minutes"];
$value_loop3["Total_Minutes"]=str_replace($find,$re,$val);
```

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` should be used in this way:

```
str_replace( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

The function's argument are search, replace, and subject, so for your case should be like : `str_replace($find,$re,$val)`